# Send "json_event" from logstash plugin to JAVA

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, logstash

I was trying to make a logstash, I was looking for a way to send the complete "event" to JAVA, so that I can do complete processing in my java project.

I was able to send individual "string" but how to send the complete "event_json"

Comment: Post your relevant configs?

Answer (score 1):

You may try and use the exec output to run a script that will do this for you and send the @message field to the needed destination.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/exec

Comment: Thnx for your response, but eventually I sent the @message field and did processing on that string ...and it worked fine;
and I never knew about exec adapter, I need it for some other purpose,thank you for that :)